# Web service Client application

Tags: java, xml, web-services

There is a .Net web service and I have to send XML data from my local applications.  My local application are running on Java & Sql.

Web service is accepting xml type. would you please help me how should I do?  is there an example for this case?

Comment: Google and you will find loads of examples. Dont expect SO will provide you link when you could do the same. Please put some effort.

Comment: I have searched google and even youtube tutorials. But I did not understand well. How should I do. So if any one did same application before may be they can advice me.

Comment: What exactly you didnt understand from what you saw or what you read?

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you 2 examples from your java application, you post an file to service.

**Apache HttpClient :**

```
String url = "https://yoururl.com"; 

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

// add header
post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xml", xmlString));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
System.out.println("Post parameters : " + post.getEntity());
System.out.println("Response Code : " + 
                            response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}

System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Here's an example how to do it with **java.net.URLConnection:**

```
String url = "http://example.com";
String charset = "UTF-8";
String param1 = URLEncoder.encode("param1", charset);
String param2 = URLEncoder.encode("param2", charset);
String query = String.format("param1=%s&param2=%s", param1, param2);

URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(url).openConnection();
urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST.
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("accept-charset", charset);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

OutputStreamWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), charset);
    writer.write(query); // Write POST query string (if any needed).
} finally {
    if (writer != null) try { writer.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
}

InputStream result = urlConnection.getInputStream();
// Now do your thing with the result.
```

Thanks

Shiva Kumar SS